# How can I convert a list of objects of class “dist” into data frame in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, distance

I have a list of objects of class `dist`. So I can extract the different `dist` components as follows:

```
# Here for factor level A

    my.results[5,]$A
               1          2          3
    2 0.74000000                      
    3 0.64150943 0.50000000           
    4 0.64814815 0.56140351 0.14285714

# And here for factor level B

    my.results[5,]$B
               1          2          3          4          5
    2 0.41176471                                            
    3 0.53846154 0.57142857                                 
    4 0.86111111 0.80000000 0.93750000                      
    5 0.68181818 0.57142857 0.77777778 0.70588235           
    6 0.42105263 0.36842105 0.64705882 0.78378378 0.62500000
```

I want to convert these into a data frame for export along the lines of the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474729/convert-object-of-class-dist-into-data-frame-in-r)

It works for one piece of the list:

```
df<- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(my.results[5,]$A), varnames = c("row", "col"))
df[df$row > df$col,]
```

The difference is I'm dealing with multiple `dist` objects and not just one. I've tried using `lapply` in combination with the linked answer but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe `stack(as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist(x))))` for a single object. And the `lapply(your_list, function(x) ... )`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me, I get `Error in dist(my.results[5, ]) :(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` when I run the `stack` line.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example to work on?